# Removing links from quick view

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't want to remove links from the product page but I have a iframe quick view which displays exactly what is there on the product page. I managed to remove additional tabs, upsells by inserting following in the layout file. I would like remove two more links "Sign up for price alert" and "Be the first to review this product". What are the tags for these two links that can be used in the layout file to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reviews**
The reviews block is created at runtime, not through XML. You can see this in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_initReviewsHelperBlock()

To remove it, you can do the following:

1. Remove `$this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)` from your `catalog/product/view.phtml` file
2. Hide it with CSS
3. Disable the Mage_Review module from outputting HTML in System > Configuration > Advanced

**Price alerts**
This block is dynamically rendered as part of the `alert_urls` block on the product page. To remove it you could:

1. Try removing the block using the same method you used for the additional tabs (via layout XML): `<remove name="productalert.price/>`
2. Hide it with CSS
3. Disable the Mage_ProductAlert module from outputting HTML in System > Configuration > Advanced

Personally I would just go with option 1 in both cases but every Magento build is different and you can decide which one is the correct choice for you.